# Running Visual Studio Test project from outside

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, powershell, windows-8

I am trying to run a Visual Studio 2012 solution with a normal c# dll project and a Unit test project(referencing the c# project dll) from a windows 8 app/ another c# project.

How do I trigger the run of the unit tests from another visual studio project?

Is there any way to trigger with a powershell script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mstest.exe` is the command line test runner.

It is documented on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155804.aspx

I see no reason this will not work from PowerShell.